# Sort dict list with itemgetter

Tags: python

Here is my dictionary:

```
a = [{"id":1,"data":{"age":16,"name":a}}, 
     {"id":3,"data":{"age":35,"name":b}}, 
     {"id":2,"data":{"age":9,"name":c}}]
```

I want to sort it by the field "age".

With `lambda` I use:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda k: k['data']['age'])
```

How to do this with `itemgetter`?

Comment: This sounds like a solution looking for a problem. What are you trying to achieve by requiring the use of `itemgetter`?

Comment: Both answers below give `sorted(a, key = lambda k : itemgetter('age')(itemgetter('data')(k)))`, which is not really an improvement over `sorted(a, key=lambda k: k['data']['age'])`.  In this case I advise ditching `itemgetter`.

Comment: `itemgetter` is **not** meant to access nested structures. It gives a very simple way of accessing elements from a sequence, but for more complicated things using a function/lambda *is* the way to go. The same holds for other situations too. For example `partial` can be used to provide some positional parameters, but if you want to specify the *second* positional parameter and leave the first without a value, then you'd better use a `lambda`(although there are gotchas... for example be careful when creating `lambda`s in a loop).

Comment: May be he just need it for homework ;)

Comment: This is actually a case where it would be nice if Python had some sort of composition operator or function: `key=compose(itemgetter('age'), itemgetter('data'))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better start by adding quotes to "a", "b" and "c", otherwise you will have a confusion between dict a and char "a"

```
a = [{"id":1,"data":{"age":16,"name":"a"}}, 
     {"id":3,"data":{"age":35,"name":"b"}}, 
     {"id":2,"data":{"age":9,"name":"c"}}]
```

For the `itemgetter` :

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [{"id":1,"data":{"age":16,"name":"a"}}, 
     {"id":3,"data":{"age":35,"name":"b"}}, 
     {"id":2,"data":{"age":9,"name":"c"}}]

l=sorted(a, key = lambda k : itemgetter('age')(itemgetter('data')(k)) )

print (l)
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Thnx, I've completed it

Answer (score 0):

You can use itlike that:

```
sorted(a, key = lambda k : itemgetter('age')(itemgetter('data')(k)) )
```

Outputs:

```
[{'data': {'age': 9, 'name': 'c'}, 'id': 2},
{'data': {'age': 16, 'name': 'a'}, 'id': 1},
{'data': {'age': 35, 'name': 'b'}, 'id': 3}]
```